# kentico get site cultures from macro

Tags: kentico

I'm using Kentico 11 and would like to get the current site's available site cultures using a Macro.

I am trying to do this from a Page Type field's data source Macro Expression. I have set the data type to Text and the Form Control to Multi Select.

The reason I am doing this is because our client has requested that some products only be available to specific site cultures (They are using site culture as locations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation would be better handled via custom SQL query on CMS_SiteCulture and join on CMS_Culture table.

Out of the box macros do not provide direct access to this binding and you would have to resort to custom macro to get a proper list(array) of items back.

Comment: Do I just hardcode the SiteID, or is there a more generic way of getting the current site using the custom SQL query? At the moment my where clause is: [CMS_SiteCulture].[SiteID] = 4

Comment: You can use macros even in SQL queries. I did a quick test on Multiple choice and dropdown list and SELECT * FROM CMS_Site WHERE SiteID = {%CurrentSite.ID#%} is resolved fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can `{%SiteContext.CurrentSite.OtherBindings.CultureSites.ItemsAsFields.CultureID%}`. This will give you the list of CultureIDs available for your site. To explore available macros and test them I suggest you go `system->macros->console`

The following will output CultureID, CultureCode, CultureName:    `{%SiteContext.CurrentSite.OtherBindings.CultureSites.Transform("{#CultureID#} {#Parent.CodeName#} {#Parent.CultureName#}<br>")%}`